# Return distinct records with the shortest length - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with Attributes, Definitions and Tokens. Tokens in this case is an abbreviation used to represent the Definition. Multiple people enter the information so the tokens are not consistent. I want to find the smallest length token for each Attribute. Examples are:

| Attribute | Definition | Token | TokenLength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product Type | Adapter | ADAPTER | 7 |
| Product Type | Adapter | ADAPTR | 6 |
| Product Type | Adapter | ADP | 3 |
| Product Type | Adapter | ADPT | 4 |
| Product Type | Adapter | ADPTR | 5 |
| Feature | Automatic | AUTO | 4 |
| Feature | Automatic | AUTO-VENT | 9 |
| Feature | Automatic | AUTOMATIC | 9 |
| Collection/Series | Classic Rib | CL-RIB | 6 |
| Collection/Series | Classic Rib | CLASSIC_R | 9 |
| Collection/Series | Classic Rib | CLASSIC_RIB | 11 |
| Collection/Series | Classic Rib | CR | 2 |

I want to results to be:

| Attribute | Definition | Token | TokenLength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product Type | Adapter | ADP | 3 |
| Feature | Automatic | AUTO | 4 |
| Collection/Series | Classic Rib | CR | 2 |

I have tried variations of LEN and MIN among others and I cannot seem to get what I am looking for. This statement has gotten me the closest, but not quite.

```
SELECT Attribute, Definition,Token, len(Token)
FROM TableName
WHERE LEN(Token) = (SELECT MIN(LEN(Token)) FROM TableName) 
ORDER BY Token
```

Answer (score 1):

Correlate the subquery:

```
SELECT Attribute, Definition, Token, len(Token)
FROM TableName t
WHERE LEN(Token) = (
    SELECT MIN(LEN(Token))
    FROM TableName a
    WHERE a.Attribute = t.Attribute
) 
ORDER BY Token
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` (or `RANK()` if you want duplicates). For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by attribute order by tokenlength) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as a correlated subquery, you can also do this using a window function:

```sql
SELECT Attribute, Definition, Token, TokenLength
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        TokenLength = LEN(Token)
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Attribute ORDER BY LEN(Token))
    FROM TableName a
) a
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Token
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use various methods for it. One of the method is to use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
Select t.* from your_table t
 Where not exists
       (Select 1 from your_table tt
         Where t.Attribute = tt.Attribute And len(tt.token) < len(t.token) )
```